# How to Seperate Array with equals to and create single array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi  I am working on very complex array operations.

I have $temp variable which stores pipe separated string like **Height=10|Width=20**

I have used explode function to convert into array and get specific output.

Below code i have try :

```
$product_attributes = explode("|",$temp)

//below output i get after the explode.

$product_attributes

Array(
       [0]=>Height=10
       [1]=>width=20
)
```

But i want to parse this array to separate one.

**My expected output :**

```
Array (
    [0]=>Array(
        [0] => Height
        [1] => 10
        )
    [1]=>Array(
        [0]=>Width
        [1]=>20     
        )

    )
```

Which function i need to used to get the desire output ?

**Before downvoting let me know if i have made any mistake**

Comment: The mistake I see that could grant you a downvote is that you have not included any code or attempts on how to solve it.

Comment: @Andreas  I  have done explode one time but second time how to use that i dont know

Comment: That is true. Sorry about that. (I have not downvoted or have any intention of doing so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code

```
<?php

$temp = "Height=10|Width=20";

$product_attributes = explode("|", $temp);

foreach ($product_attributes as $k => $v) {
    $product_attributes[$k] = explode('=', $v);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($product_attributes);
?>
```

check running answer [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gtaf-zn71)

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below code. I've tested this and it outputs the result you've shown in your post.

```
$temp = 'Height=10|Width=20';
$product_attributes = explode('|', $temp);
$product_attributes2 = array();
foreach ($product_attributes as $attribute) {
    $product_attributes2[] = explode('=', $attribute);
}
print_r($product_attributes2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Process your result by this:

```
$f = function($value) { return explode('=', $value); }
$result = array_map($f, $product_attributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option is to split the values in to one array and then build them from there.

```
$str = "Height=10|Width=20";
$arr = preg_split("/\||=/", $str);

$arr2= array();
$j=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    $arr2[$j][]= $arr[$i];
    $arr2[$j][]= $arr[$i+1];
    $i++;
    $j++;

}
var_dump($arr2);
```

The output will be:

```
$arr = array(4){
         0  =>  Height
         1  =>  10
         2  =>  Width
         3  =>  20
        }

$arr2 = array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "Height"
        [1]=>
        string(2) "10"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "Width"
        [1]=>
        string(2) "20"
      }
    }
```